# How to select columns based on value they contain pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am working in pandas with a certain dataset that describes the population of a certain country per year. The dataset is construed in a weird way wherein the years aren't the columns themselves but rather the years are a value within the first row of the set. The dataset describes every year from 1960 up til now but I only need 1970, 1980, 1990 etc. For this purpose I've created a list with all those years and tried to make a new dataset which is equivalent to the old one but only has the columns that contain a value from said list so I don't have all this extra info I'm not using. Online I can only find instructions for removing rows or selecting by column name, since both these criteria don't apply in this situation I thought i should ask here.
The dataset is a csv file which I've downloaded off some world population site. [here a link to a screenshot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc1Oc.png)

As you can see the years are given in scientific notation for some years, which is also how I've added them to my list.

```
pop = pd.read_csv('./maps/API_SP.POP.TOTL_DS2_en_csv_v2_10576638.csv', 

header=None, engine='python', skiprows=4)
display(pop)
years = ['1.970000e+03','1.980000e+03','1.990000e+03','2.000000e+03','2.010000e+03','2.015000e+03', 'Country Name']
pop[pop.columns[pop.isin(years).any()]]
```

This is one of the things I've tried so far which I thought made the most sense, but I am still very new to pandas so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That selection is extremely confusing, at least to me. Are you trying to keep only columns if any of their rows contain a given value? I suggest you produce a [mcve] with sample data and your expected output that way your problem more transparent.

Comment: As an aside (somewhat), years as column headers is fine for display, but data processing / analysis is likely going to be easier if you reshape your data. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data for reference, and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html

Comment: Also, I was able to find the data you are using (since it's public, why not post the URL?) at https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/sp.pop.totl, and when I read in the CSV file using `pd.read_csv(<path>, skiprows=4)`, I don't get strange scientific notation year headings for my column names.

Answer (score 1):

Using the data at https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/sp.pop.totl, copied into pastebin (first time using the service, so apologies if it doesn't work for some reason):

```
# actual code using CSV file saved to desktop
#df = pd.read_csv(<path to CSV>, skiprows=4)

# pastebin for reproducibility
df = pd.read_csv(r'https://pastebin.com/raw/LmdGySCf',sep='\t')

# manually select years and other columns of interest
colsX = ['Country Name', 'Country Code', 'Indicator Name', 'Indicator Code',
         '1990', '1995', '2000'] 
dfX = df[colsX]

# select every fifth year
colsY = df.filter(regex='19|20', axis=1).columns[[int(col) % 5 == 0 for col in df.filter(regex='19|20', axis=1).columns]]
dfY = df[colsY]
```

As a general comment:

> The dataset is construed in a weird way wherein the years aren't the columns themselves but rather the years are a value within the first row of the set.

This is not correct. Viewing the CSV file, it is quite clear that row 5 (*Country Name, Country Code, Indicator Name, Indicator Code, 1960, 1961, ...*) **are indeed column names**. You have read the data into pandas in such a way that those values are not column years, but your first step, before trying to subset your data, should be to ensure you have read in the data properly -- which, in this case, would give you column headers named for each year.